# Pattern recognition in OpenCV using Python

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

Currently I am trying to create a pattern recognition program as a pet project. It involves jpeg files of knitting swatches and basically recognizing the stitches out of the swatch. Each stitch essentially takes the shape of an inverted 'v'.

So far have managed to get current versions of OpenCV in Python up and running in a Visual Studio environment using the inbuilt Canny Edge detection but am unsure how to progress from there because am reading up on edge detection methods and finding there are quite many.

If anyone can point me in the right way would appreciate it a lot.

So heres the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Defining the autocanny function 
def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.10):
     #compute median of image thresholds
     v = np.median(image)

     #apply automatic canny edge detection using the computed median
     lower = int(max(0,(1.0 - sigma) * v))
     upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
     edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)

     #return the edged image
     return edged

#defining the image, grayscale, blurred
image = cv2.imread('img_knit_sample2.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)

#apply Canny edge detection using a wide threshold, tight
#threshold, and automatically determined threshold 
wide = cv2.Canny(blurred, 10, 200)
tight = cv2.Canny(blurred, 225, 250)
auto = auto_canny(blurred)

#show the images
cv2.imshow("Original", image)
cv2.imshow("Edges-wide", wide)
cv2.imshow("Edges-tight", tight)
cv2.imshow("Edges-auto", auto)

#Save the images to disk
cv2.imwrite('Wide_config.jpg', wide)
cv2.imwrite('Tight_config.jpg', tight)
cv2.imwrite('Autocanny.jpg', auto)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Unfortunately i cannot upload more than 2 images but am more than happy to get the URL's for anyone willing to go further

[image: Original]

[image: Autocanny_config]

(Apologies for the crappy description since I am new to this and if you do understand my query and can still help then kudos and much appreciation to you)

Cheers

Comment: Please add samples of your input, and some additional picture(s) that will help illustrate what it is you're trying to achieve. You can use something like imgur to host them. It might also be useful if you [edit] the question and add a [mcve] that shows what you've got so far.

Comment: Thanks Dan! Will do just give me a couple of minutes..

Comment: Hope this works Dan :)

Comment: Yep, good improvement. It's a tough one tho :) One thing that strikes me -- maybe instead of just converting to gray, you should go to HSV and use the `V` channel, to make it less sensitive to the color. Check [this out](http://i.imgur.com/PsqYEPr.png) -- the left is `BGR2GRAY`, right is `BGR2HSV` using the third channel of the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan! appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem. Maybe explore some of the feature detection algorithms available in OpenCV.

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/07/local-binary-patterns-with-python-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

Edges appear where there is contrast, i.e. at the limit between zones of a different color (intensity). In your picture, this is essentially between the blue and black wools.

You can see some separation between the blue threads, but these are ridges, not edges, and you'd better use a ridge detector.

In the black areas, seeing the edges is hopeless. Don't even try.

If your goal is to locate the stitches, you may be more lucky with template matching.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion Yves ! I will look up more into it :)

Comment: how might i implement template matching? is there any direction you can point me in

Comment: I am but my skill in it is quite nascent so am in the reading up stage and have never really studied image processing. I imagine that opencv does have template matching so currentley looking up tutorial docs on the like

Comment: In any case thanks for the suggestion though. it makes sense what you are suggesting to implement

Comment: @MukulBhaskar: in any case, don't expect too good results, this is a hard case.